# over-riding a variable from a extended class

Tags: java

Although I know we can't over-ride a variable in Java, maybe there is a way around to do the same thing in a different way.

So I have a `Base` class with some stuff

```
class Base
{
    // some stuff here;
}
```

I have another class which extends the `Base` class and adds some extra stuff

```
class New1 extends Base
{
    //lots and lots of stuff here

    String[] str = {"a", "b", "c"};

    //lots and lots of stuff here
}
```

Now I need a class which extends class new1 just with a modified `String[] str` as

```
String[] str = {"l", "m", "n"};
```

I can't afford writing my new class which extends from base class and rewriting all stuff class `New1` with the modified string, the class MUST come from class new1 and with the new overrided string.

Comment: If you already know that "we can't override a variable", why are you asking about how to override a variable?

Comment: So provide a protected constructor taking the array in new1, or use a protected getter to access the array. Try something.

Answer (score 0):

If `str` is protected (or package private and your new sub-class is in the same package as `new1`), you can do :

```
class c extends new1
{
    public c ()
    {
        super();
        str = {"l", "m", "n"};
    }

}
```

Or, you can do the same by passing `{"l", "m", "n"}` to a constructor of `new1`, which would overwrite the value of `str`.

```
class c extends new1
{
    public c ()
    {
        super({"l", "m", "n"});
    }

}
```

You wouldn't be overriding the variable, just changing its value.

Comment: add what if the str in parent class is final ?

Comment: yeah the second approach looks doable

Comment: @VarunChitre If it's final, there's no way to change its value. You can define an array of the same name in the new sub-class, but it wouldn't be overriding the original array, it would just be hiding it.

Comment: I see. the thing is I can't modify class new1 as well to receive the constructor parameter array. So there is no possible solution to this apparently